# How to call a class method on a module that overrides some methods of another module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance

There's a module in a different namespace that I was using. Specifically I was using a class method defined in it (`class_method_message` in this example).

I now want to change some behaviour of the module, so I thought of creating a new one, extending the original, and overriding the methods I wanted to change.

This is shown below, and doesn't seem to be working as expected.

```
module OriginalSpace
  module OriginalModuleThatICantEdit
    def self.class_method_message
      puts "the message is: #{get_message}"
    end

    def self.get_message
      "hello"
    end
  end
end

module MySpace
  module MyExtensionOfThatModule
    extend OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit

    def self.get_message
      "byebye"
    end
  end
end

# This works
OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.class_method_message

# This doesn't: `undefined method `class_method_message' for MySpace::MyExtensionOfThatModule:Module (NoMethodError)`
MySpace::MyExtensionOfThatModule.class_method_message
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`class_method_message` is defined on the *eigenclass* of `OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit`. That said, extending the latter makes not much sense, you need to extend it’s eigenclass.

The common approach to update the original module with new functionality here would be to prepend the desired behaviour to the eigenclass using [`Module#prepend`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-prepend):

```
OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.singleton_class.prepend(Module.new do
  def get_message
    "byebye"
  end
end)

OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.class_method_message
#⇒ the message is: byebye
```

Note, that both `class_method_message` and `get_message` are declared on the *eigenclass*, which is a *class* not a *module*. That said one cannot just import them into the module using `include` and/or `extend`.

Comment: So, is there any way to access class_method_message in MySpace::MyExtensionOfThatModule?

Comment: Define “access.” You might call it. You cannot expect it to be calling yours.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps I'm missing something, but if you want to change the functionality of a module, why don't you just do it directly, rather than resorting to including, prepending or extending another module? It's more direct and you can remove methods as well as add or modify methods.

```
module OriginalSpace
  module OriginalModuleThatICantEdit
    def self.class_method_message
      puts "the message is: #{get_message}"
    end    
    def self.huh
      "huh"
    end    
    def self.get_message
      "hello"
    end
  end
end

OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.class_method_message
  #=> "the message is: hello"

OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.methods(false)
  #=> [:class_method_message, :huh, :get_message]
```

Let's remove (the *module* method) `huh` and redefine `get_message`.

```
module OriginalSpace
  module OriginalModuleThatICantEdit
    singleton_class.send(:undef_method, :huh)    
    def self.get_message
      "byebye"
    end
  end
end

OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.class_method_message
  #=> "the message is: byebye"

OriginalSpace::OriginalModuleThatICantEdit.methods(false)
  #=> [:class_method_message, :get_message]
```

We must use `send` in `singleton_class.send(:undef_method, :huh)` because [Module#undef](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/Module.html#method-i-undef_method) is a private method.

Answer (score -3):

Just a suggestion.

Instead of creating a new module, You can also use module_eval to override the existing module.